Convert magnetic field strength H to magnetic field density B
I want to convert physical quantity 'magnetic field strength' H with unit 'A/m' into 'magnetic flux density' B with unit 'T' (Tesla). I can calculate B=µ0*H, where µ0 is magnetic permeability of free space with unit 'Tesla meters per Ampere' or 'H/m (Henrys per meter)'.
# Define the value in A/m
ampere_per_meter_value = 1000 * ureg("A/m") 

# Convert A/m to Tesla
tesla_value = ampere_per_meter_value.to("T")

Looking at the default pint units definition file I see units defined for magnetic field strength, magnetic field, magnetic flux and inductance. Having µ0 defined, pint should be able to do the conversion, but it does not, see error:
pint Error: pint.errors.DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from 'ampere / meter' ([current] / [length]) to 'tesla' ([mass] / [time] ** 2 / [current])

Any hints for me?

As you wrote, to get B from H, you need to multiply with µ0. You do not do that in the code.

I thought pint would do that for me using .to method?!

Pint does not convert one quantity to another quantity, it converts the same quantity from one unit to another unit (as far as I understand).

thank you @mkrieger1 for opening my eyes, I found my solutions with pint 'contexts'.

Pint has the concept of 'contexts' to convert between dimensions based on some pre-established (physical) relationships. I added this to my code to solve my specific problem:
ureg.enable_contexts('Gaussian')

